# ld: library not found for -lPods-App clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode5

I'm trying to build my application on the iPhonesimulator 7.1.
via command line :

```
xcodebuild \
-project MyProject.xcodeproj \
-configuration Debug \
VALID_ARCHS="arm6 armv7 i386" \
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="2" \
-arch i386 \
-sdk iphonesimulator7.1 \
```

And I've got a installation fail:

"ld: library not found for -lPods- My app
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** INSTALL FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    Ld /MyAppName normal i386
(1 failure)

"
I've installed pods, cleaned application folder and so on...
It's possible to build app from Xcode UI, but I rely need to bold it from command line for future purposes.

Please advice.

Comment: You've edited your answer from "Pods-Marc O'Polo" to "My App" in order to keep the name anonymous, however it's *that name*, specifically, which is causing the issue.  Therefore you cannot use that name anyway, so it's pointless attempting to cover your tracks.

Answer (score 1):

The name *Pods-Marc O'Polo* will cause all sorts of issues with command line utilities:

- The name contains a space, which means unless the option `-lPods-Marc O'Polo` is enclosed in double quotes, the compiler will consider it to be two options.
- The name contains a single quote, which means the shell running the command line utilty will look for a closing quote.

In short, it's unusable in that form.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a point of problem. I'm not using name with space in shell command. Those you saw were from logs.

Comment: @user3752741 Why do you say that?

Comment: You see, if I enter incorrect name shell wont work at all. *-lPods-App Name* - it's not a command, but just a log. Im just cant install builded app on simulator

Comment: Anyway, i've tried your suggestion. It doesn't wok... So, i'll need another solution

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got a solution. You just need to enter xcappworckspace as a path to your project, and mention the build method fo it.